# как при сохранении формы передать данные в поле модели? django form models save

Tags: python, django

получаю форму и обрабатываю в post. Надо сохранить в модель уникальный uuid записи
делаю это так: `formOne.save(related_uuid=related_uuid)`

но не работает, ошибка - `save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'related_uuid'`

**models**

```
class Orders(models.Model):
    device = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Что ремонтируем')
    uuid = models.CharField(max_length=22, blank=True, verbose_name='uuid')
```

**views**

```
class OrderAddView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'orders/order_add.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ... some work code
        return self.render_to_response(context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        formOne = SimpleOrderAddForm(self.request.POST, prefix='one_form')        
        if formOne.is_valid():
            related_uuid = shortuuid.uuid()           
            formOne.save(related_uuid=related_uuid)            
            return HttpResponseRedirect('orders_home')
        else:
            print('NotValid')
            return self.form_invalid(formOne, **kwargs)

    def form_invalid(self, formOne,, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        ... some work code
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

Comment: `formOne.save(uuid =related_uuid)`

Comment: ответ - https://stackoverflow.com/a/66670678/9653855